# `QRCode` package and `polyglossia`

Tags: polyglossia, qrcode

I think there may be a problem with QRCode when using polyglossia.

In the MWE below, I want to encode a web address (ascii text, no strange unicode characters). I get an error when the main language is Arabic, but no error if the main language is English.  I have tried using `\begin{english}` and also `\textenglish` but still get an error.

The error message I receive says

> Splitting off block ١   Making error block 1

Notice the inconsistent arabic and english digits 
Then I get

> Missing \endcsname inserted.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.50]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Script=Latin]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}
\qrcode{www.google.com}
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't test with `Times New Roman` and `Linux Libertine O`, using different fonts there is is no problem

Comment: which fonts are you using?

Comment: Imho is is a bug in qrcode, it seems to use `\theqr@i` (which calls `\@arabic` which is redefined by bidi), in places where a `\number\c@qr@i` or something like this would be better.

Comment: It work fine with `\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}`